# MVC APi with Entity framework, best way to update?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I am working on a project that uses an MVC API with Entity Framework 6.1.3. We need to implement Get, GET/ID, Insert, Update and Delete API's.

for Insert and Update we have a parameter class that is not the same one as the DB, i am not sure what will be the best solution for that.

For an Update (the one that i have more questions) i can find a record and then update all properties manually, this is something i want to avoid. If i use the currentvalues from the entity then i will have to set the ExtraValues properties in all the apis that i am going to write, that kind of looks weird.

Note: i want to have a child class since most of the entities uses the same fields (Created/Updated) so instead of having those in all the classes i rather have them as inheritance.

There has to be a better solution for this problem, could someone help with ideas or best ways to do this.

```
    public class DBClassA : ExtraValues
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class DBClassB : ExtraValues
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    //This will be use in all the classes
    public class ExtraValues
    {
        public string SameValueInOtherClasses { get; set; }
        public string SameValueInOtherClasses2 { get; set; }
        public string SameValueInOtherClasses3 { get; set; }
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public List<DBClassA> Get()
    {
        return new List<DBClassA>();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public DBClassA Get(int ID)
    {
        return new DBClassA();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Insert(DBClassA obj)
    {
        using (var context = new DBEntities())
        {
            context.Entity.Attach(DBClassA);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }

    [HttpPut]
    public HttpResponseMessage Update(int ID, DBClassA obj)
    {
        using (var context = new DBEntities())
        {
            var entity = context.Entity.Find(ID);
            //I will have to put the ExtraValues here
            obj.ExtraValues = "";
            _context.Entry(entity).CurrentValues.SetValues(obj);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using (var db = new DBEntities())
{
    db.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

more info: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/update-entity-using-dbcontext.aspx